# Splitting Raster in ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have a 30m raster dataset for the continental US, and would like to divide it into manageable chunks to convert it to vector, etc.

What's the best way to accomplish this? I don't want any overlap within the tiles, and don't care about the shape of the resulting rasters. The [Split Raster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.2/index.html#//00170000009v000000) tool in ArcGIS would seem the natural choice, but it requires that I specify a resampling method. I don't want to resample my data at all-- I want this the same data as the original raster, just in smaller pieces.

Happy to pursue python-based solutions if need be, but hoping there's some out of the box solution that doesn't involve transforming the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your output rasters (as defined in the environment of your tool):

- have the same output cell size,
- have their pixels aligned with the input raster

Then you can use the Split raster tool using the "NEAREST" option for resampling. This will not modifiy your pixel values.

Answer (score 1):

Even though the Split Raster tool defaults to a re-sample method, it does not change the size of the pixels unless you specify a size change under the "Other options" drop down. I would just use this tool, it works well.