# Splitting .tif image into several tiles?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, tiles, digital-image-processing

I have an image of size 1GB (.tif), with the width and height 94000x71680. I would like to chunk this image into 20000X20000 tiles so that I can process them.

How can I do this?

Comment: Anup, https://github.com/mapbox/rasterio would give you numpy array(s) of your input data. You could split that using numpy o scipy methods and save each part to a new file easily. Would such solution qualify? If so, you need to say how the "uneven bits" (71680 is not cleanly divisible by 20000) should be treated.

Comment: In QGIS, if you have the Processing plugin installed and active, you get additional menu items on the Raster menu, one of which is Extraction.  This has "Clip Raster by Extent" on it, which is a screen that allows you to draw a box around an area and save as a GeoTiff.  This allowed me to drop unwanted areas on huge tiffs, and processing time dropped significantly.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I propose two solutions: the first one using QGIS, the second one using Python (GDAL).

---

### Solution using QGIS

In QGIS you may create a VRT mosaic.

Please follow this procedure (see the image below):

1. Load the raster in the **Layers Panel**;
2. Right-click on it and choose `Save As...`;
3. Check the `Create VRT` option;
4. Choose the folder where your outputs will be saved;
5. Set the extent (if you want to work on the whole raster, don't modify anything);
6. Choose if using the current resolution (I suggest to leave it as default);
7. Set the max number of columns and rows (in your case, it should be 20000 columns and 2000 rows);
8. Press the `OK` button.

[image]

For example, the using of the parameters in the above dialog on this sample raster (the parameters I set are chosen randomly):

[image]

will generate 100 tiles in the path specified at step 4:

[image]

Loading them in QGIS, they look like this:

[image]

As @bugmenot123 correctly said in the comments, the result looks weird just because the style of each image fits itself to the distribution of values per image (but the data are perfectly fine).

---

### Solution using Python (GDAL)

Another way to obtain the same result is the using of GDAL ([gdal_translate](http://www.gdal.org/gdal_translate.html)).

With reference to the same example described above, you may use this script:

```
import os, gdal

in_path = 'C:/Users/Marco/Desktop/'
input_filename = 'dtm_5.tif'

out_path = 'C:/Users/Marco/Desktop/output_folder/'
output_filename = 'tile_'

tile_size_x = 50
tile_size_y = 70

ds = gdal.Open(in_path + input_filename)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
xsize = band.XSize
ysize = band.YSize

for i in range(0, xsize, tile_size_x):
    for j in range(0, ysize, tile_size_y):
        com_string = "gdal_translate -of GTIFF -srcwin " + str(i)+ ", " + str(j) + ", " + str(tile_size_x) + ", " + str(tile_size_y) + " " + str(in_path) + str(input_filename) + " " + str(out_path) + str(output_filename) + str(i) + "_" + str(j) + ".tif"
        os.system(com_string)
```

You obviously need to adapt the values to your specific case.

Comment: Just a quick comment that the example of how QGIS renders them looks weird just because the style fits itself to the distribution of values *per image*. The data is perfectly fine :)

Comment: Thanks, first of all for your answer really helpful, But i want achieve same result using python? Can you help me on that also Because it's more manual rather then programmatic so.

Comment: @bugmenot123 Thanks, I edit the answer with your useful comment.

Comment: @Anup Panwar, if I find a solution with PyQGIS, I'll edit my answer! =)

Comment: @HowToInQGIS Thanks, for else if you want a way in python that also will help :)

Comment: @AnupPanwar see the edit and let me know if it works! =)

Comment: @HowToInQGIS add GDAL Documentation Links also, so that other can also understand about it. :)

Comment: @HowToInQGIS Sorry man i forgot :)

Comment: If I know I only want to divide the rasters in half (North to South), how do I know how many rows and columns to make?

Comment: Another solution is to use GRASS GIS which can do that easily: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass74/manuals/r.tile.html - for a Python script style approach you can then use grass-session (see e.g. https://neteler.gitlab.io/grass-gis-analysis/…)

Answer (score 6):

**Don't split**

You [gdalbuildvrt](http://www.gdal.org/gdalbuildvrt.html), you can create virtual tiles that will only use a few bytes on your disk. Then you can use most softwares that will take your vrt's as input to perform your processing.

Alternatively, I would rather look for a tool that can work with a 1Gb image than split and merge an image. For instance, OTB has most of the capabilities for standard (and sometimes advanced) image processing with large images. You can [wrap OTB](https://wiki.orfeo-toolbox.org/index.php/OTB-Wrapper) for Python or run it from QGIS or from command lines.

Answer (score 6):

Another solution using **GDAL** is the **gdal_retile.py** tool:

```
mkdir image_tiles
gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 1 -ps 20000 20000 -co "TILED=YES" -co "COMPRESS=JPEG" -targetDir image_tiles big_input_image.tif
```

For more Information see: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_retile.html

Comment: Please note that this solution does not create separate files, but just adds internal reorganization of the raster data to allow quick access to various zoom levels and/or partial display of the raster.

Answer (score 2):

Using the *Split Raster* tool, you can split a raster into tiles based on a few methods of division including the *size of each tile* or the *number of tiles*.

Also see [Splitting Raster in ArcGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/141258/splitting-raster-in-arcgis)