# Using advanced settings of GDAL_rasterize in QGIS script

Tags: qgis, gdal, qgis-processing, gdal-rasterize

I’m working on a script (that later should be used in a processing model) that uses **gdal_rasterize** to write different attribute values (columns) in different bands of one raster file.

I know that this I possible with gdal_rasterize using the **-b** and **-burn** flags. 
Anyway, I can’t manage to integrate this commands in my QGIS-Python script. Am I missing something with the syntax?

Here is the GDAL synopsis:

```
Usage: gdal_rasterize [-b band]* [-i] [-at]
   {[-burn value]* | [-a attribute_name] | [-3d]} [-add]
   [-l layername]* [-where expression] [-sql select_statement]
   [-dialect dialect] [-of format] [-a_srs srs_def]
   [-co "NAME=VALUE"]* [-a_nodata value] [-init value]*
   [-te xmin ymin xmax ymax] [-tr xres yres] [-tap] [-ts width height]
   [-ot {Byte/Int16/UInt16/UInt32/Int32/Float32/Float64/
         CInt16/CInt32/CFloat32/CFloat64}] [-q]
   <src_datasource> <dst_filename>
```

And here is my script so far:

```
 ##Rasterize_GDAL_KRK=name
 ##Input=vector
 ##Output=output raster
 ##Extent=extent
 ##cellsize=number 25

import os, processing, osgeo.gdal

processing.runalg('gdalogr:rasterize',
                                        {"INPUT":Input,
                                        "FIELD":"KRK_1",
                                        "DIMENSIONS":1,
                                        "WIDTH":cellsize,
                                        "HEIGHT":cellsize,
                                        "RAST_EXT":Extent,
                                        "TFW":0,
                                        "RTYPE":0,
                                        "NO_DATA":None,
                                        "COMPRESS":0,
                                        "JPEGCOMPRESSION":1,
                                        "ZLEVEL":1,
                                        "PREDICTOR":1,
                                        "TILED":False,
                                        "BIGTIFF":3,
                                        "EXTRA": None,
                                        "OUTPUT":Output})
```

Comment: I think it's not possible to add extra flags when using gdal from Processing. Are you able to directly call GDAL through Python?

Comment: That is what I was wondering! If it is possible to directly call GDAL through Python, I don’t know how to do it...

Answer (score 1):

From the algorithm dialog you should see something like this:

[image]

which is a call from GDAL using Processing. So, I think it should be enough starting from it for creating your own script.

You may try using this code (you should edit the `com_string` string by adding your specific parameters, including the extra flags):

```
##Rasterize_GDAL_KRK=name
##Input=vector
##Output=output raster
##Extent=extent
##cellsize=number 25

import os, gdal
import processing


ex = Extent.split(',')
ext = str(ex[0]) + "," + str(ex[1]) + "," + str(ex[2]) + "," + str(ex[3])

com_string = "gdal_rasterize -a KRK_1 -ot 0 -of GTiff -te " +  ext + " -tr " + str(cellsize) +" " + str(cellsize) + " -co COMPRESS=NONE -co BIGTIFF=IF_NEEDED -l " + str(Input)
os.system(com_string)
```

As a first step, I suggest you to initially copy-and-paste only what you see in the Processing dialog after having set your input parameters, and then trying to add your extra flags in the code.

Comment: All right, I will try that and report back.

Comment: @Miron I edited the code. Now it should be easier to adapt it to your case.

Comment: I tryed the code (I think a " is missing at the end, but it still gives me "SyntaxError: invalid syntax". Don't know what I'm missig...

Comment: The error is certainly in the `com_string` string (in [this](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/221677/87487) answer, the syntax for calling GDAL worked). Could you please paste here what you see in the GDAL console from the algorithm dialog (with your parameters)?

Answer (score 0):

I finally solved the problem, it must have had something to do with the com_string string. At the end, I used the following code:

```
##Rasterize_GDAL_KRK_3.4=name
##Input=vector
##KRK_Feld=field Input
##Output=folder
##Extent=extent
##Zellengroesse=number 25

import os, gdal
import processing

shapefile = Input
(shapefilefilepath, shapefilename) = os.path.split(shapefile)
(shapefileshortname, extension) = os.path.splitext(shapefilename)

outrastername = shapefileshortname + '.tif'
outraster = Output + '/' + outrastername

ex = Extent.split(',')
ext = str(ex[0]) + " " + str(ex[1]) + " " + str(ex[2]) + " " + str(ex[3])

os.system('gdal_rasterize -a ' + str(KRK_Feld) + ' -ot Byte -of GTiff -co COMPRESS=NONE -co BIGTIFF=IF_NEEDED -te ' + ext + ' -tr ' + str(Zellengroesse) + ' ' + str(Zellengroesse) + ' -l ' + shapefileshortname +' ' +  shapefile + ' ' + outraster)
```

Now I just need to add the `-b` and `-burn` flag.