# Generating 512*512 tiles?

Tags: gdal, tiles, software-recommendations

I want to generate tiles in custom size but can't find a tiler that can do it.
In gdal2tiles I cant find the size option.
TileMapper costs too much.

Is there any opensource utils that can generate tiles in custom sizes?

Comment: You could just modify the script - change the init values: https://github.com/OSGeo/gdal/blob/trunk/gdal/swig/python/scripts/gdal2tiles.py

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the gdal_retile.py tool with the option `-levels 1`:

```
mkdir image_tiles
gdal_retile.py -v -r bilinear -levels 1 -ps 512 512 -co "TILED=YES"  -targetDir image_tiles big_input_image.tif
```

For more Information see: http://www.gdal.org/gdal_retile.html

Your can find futher solutions for QGIS, ArcGIS and gdal_translate under the following link: [How to split a .tif image into several tiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221671/how-to-split-a-tif-image-into-several-tiles)