# How to split multiband image into image tiles using Rasterio?

Tags: python, raster, imagery, numpy, rasterio

I have been using [this answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/221677/8104) on GIS SE to split 3-band (RGB) imagery into 256x256 3-band image tiles:

```
import os, gdal

in_path = '/path/to/indata/'
input_filename = 'dtm_5.tif'

out_path = '/path/to/output_folder/'
output_filename = 'tile_'

tile_size_x = 256
tile_size_y = 256

ds = gdal.Open(in_path + input_filename)
band = ds.GetRasterBand(1)
xsize = band.XSize
ysize = band.YSize

for i in range(0, xsize, tile_size_x):
    for j in range(0, ysize, tile_size_y):
        com_string = "gdal_translate -of GTIFF -srcwin " + str(i)+ ", " + str(j) + ", " + str(tile_size_x) + ", " + str(tile_size_y) + " " + str(in_path) + str(input_filename) + " " + str(out_path) + str(output_filename) + str(i) + "_" + str(j) + ".tif"
        os.system(com_string)
```

Is there a comparable [Rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) or numpy approach?

Comment: Just a suggestion but using gdal_translate with os.system will work much faster if you use subprocess.Popen(['gdal_translate','-of','GTIFF'.... you can generate a bunch of them and have them working simultaneously up to the bottleneck of HDD access. With trying to do this directly with GDAL you need to create a new dataset on each iteration, calculate the upper left and set the geotransform then read from source / write to target.. it's just easier to do it using gdal_translate.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Below is a simple example (`rasterio` 1.0.0 or later, won't work in 0.3.6). There might be better/simpler ways (and there is an [easier way](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/windowed-rw.html?highlight=block_shapes#blocks) if your raster is internally tiled and the tile block sizes match your desired output tile size).

The `rasterio` docs have some examples of [concurrent processing](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/concurrency.html) if you want to go down that road.

```
import os
from itertools import product
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio import windows

in_path = '/path/to/indata/'
input_filename = 'dtm_5.tif'

out_path = '/path/to/output_folder/'
output_filename = 'tile_{}-{}.tif'

def get_tiles(ds, width=256, height=256):
    nols, nrows = ds.meta['width'], ds.meta['height']
    offsets = product(range(0, nols, width), range(0, nrows, height))
    big_window = windows.Window(col_off=0, row_off=0, width=nols, height=nrows)
    for col_off, row_off in  offsets:
        window =windows.Window(col_off=col_off, row_off=row_off, width=width, height=height).intersection(big_window)
        transform = windows.transform(window, ds.transform)
        yield window, transform


with rio.open(os.path.join(in_path, input_filename)) as inds:
    tile_width, tile_height = 256, 256

    meta = inds.meta.copy()

    for window, transform in get_tiles(inds):
        print(window)
        meta['transform'] = transform
        meta['width'], meta['height'] = window.width, window.height
        outpath = os.path.join(out_path,output_filename.format(int(window.col_off), int(window.row_off)))
        with rio.open(outpath, 'w', **meta) as outds:
            outds.write(inds.read(window=window))
```

Answer (score 2):

I wanted an overlap of tiles for my application. Solved it by extending @user2856 to include 'overlap' as a parameter.

```
import os
import math
from itertools import product
import rasterio as rio
from rasterio import windows

def get_tiles(ds, tile_width, tile_height, overlap):
    nols, nrows = ds.meta['width'], ds.meta['height']
    xstep = tile_width - overlap
    ystep = tile_height - overlap
    for x in range(0, nols, xstep):
        if x + tile_width > nols:
            x = nols - tile_width
        for y in range(0, nrows, ystep):
            if y + tile_height > nrows:
                y = nrows - tile_height
            window = windows.Window(x, y, tile_width, tile_height)
            transform = windows.transform(window, ds.transform)
            yield window, transform

in_path = '/content/drive/MyDrive/Raster_Dataset_Airports/Spacenet'
input_filename = 'Minsk.tif'

out_path = 'Minsk_Tiles'
output_filename = 'Minsk_{}-{}.tif'

tile_width = 512
tile_height = 512
overlap = 128

with rio.open(os.path.join(in_path, input_filename)) as src:
    metadata = src.meta.copy()

    for window, transform in get_tiles(src, tile_width, tile_height, overlap):
        metadata['transform'] = transform
        metadata['width'], metadata['height'] = window.width, window.height
        out_filepath = os.path.join(out_path, output_filename.format(window.col_off, window.row_off))
        
        with rio.open(out_filepath, 'w', **metadata) as dst:
            dst.write(src.read(window=window))
```

Here is a verification mechanism to compare with the GDAL CLI command.

```
!gdal_retile.py  -ps 512 512 -overlap 128  -targetDir  Minsk_Tiles2 \
   /content/drive/MyDrive/Raster_Dataset_Airports/Spacenet/Minks.tif
```

Generate tile index files for both tiles folder and view them in GIS software.

```
!gdaltindex gdal_gen_index.shp /content/Minsk_Tiles/*.tif
!gdaltindex rasterio_gen_index.shp /content/Minsk_Tiles2 /*.tif
            

import geopandas as gpd

gdf_gdal=gpd.read_file('/content/gdal_gen_index.shp')
gdf_rasterio=gpd.read_file('/content/rasterio_gen_index.shp')
```

Answer (score 0):

This script efficiently tile a Raster by using GDAL instead of GdalTranslate or GdalWarp

https://gist.github.com/mustafateke/52f8b52804450cabd6bce7c7c9d49d21

```
# This script is created by Mustafa Teke (mustafa.teke@gmail.com)
# 17/08/2021

import math
import os
import gdal
from datetime import datetime

#Save subset ROI to given path
def subsetGeoTiff(ds, outFileName, arr_out, start, size, bands ):

    driver = gdal.GetDriverByName("GTiff")
    #set compression
    outdata = driver.Create(outFileName, size[0], size[1], bands, gdal.GDT_UInt16)
    newGeoTransform = list( ds.GetGeoTransform() )
    newGeoTransform[0] = newGeoTransform[0] + start[0]*newGeoTransform[1] + start[1]*newGeoTransform[2]
    newGeoTransform[3] = newGeoTransform[3] + start[0]*newGeoTransform[4] + start[1]*newGeoTransform[5]

    outdata.SetGeoTransform( newGeoTransform )    
    outdata.SetProjection(ds.GetProjection())

    for i in range(0,bands) :
        outdata.GetRasterBand(i+1).WriteArray(arr_out[i, :, :])
        outdata.GetRasterBand(i+1).SetNoDataValue(0)

    outdata.FlushCache()
    outdata = None

startTime = datetime.now()
print("Start" , datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"))

Path = "D:/Git/Scripts/T37SEB_20200825.tif"
outDir, file_extension = os.path.splitext(Path)
filename = os.path.split(outDir)[1]
#Create a folder in the same name as the image
if not os.path.exists(filename):
    os.makedirs(filename)

#Open dataset and get contents as a numpy array
ds = gdal.Open(Path)
image = ds.ReadAsArray()

imageWidth = ds.RasterXSize 
imageHeight = ds.RasterYSize

tileSizeX = 256
tileSizeY = 256

offsetX = int(tileSizeX/2)
offsetY = int(tileSizeY/2)

tileSize = (tileSizeY, tileSizeX)


for startX in range(0, imageWidth, offsetX):
    for startY in range(0, imageHeight, offsetY):
        endX = startX + tileSizeX
        endY = startY + tileSizeY

        currentTile = image[:, startX:endX,startY:endY]
        #if you want to save save directly with opencv
        # However reverse order of data
        #cv2.imwrite(filename + '_%d_%d' % (nTileY, nTileX)  + file_extension, currentTile)
        start = (startY,startX)
        outFullFileName = os.path.join( outDir, filename + '_%d_%d' % (startY, startX)  + file_extension )
        subsetGeoTiff(ds, outFullFileName, currentTile, start, tileSize,  currentTile.shape[0] )


endTime = datetime.now()
ds=None

print("Finished " , datetime.now().strftime("%m/%d/%Y, %H:%M:%S"), " in  " , endTime-startTime )
```