# Cropping an image while maintaining the coordinates in Python

Tags: clip

I have a 5120 X 5120 TIFF image, and I want to crop it to 25 small images of 1024 X 1024. How can I do it while maintaining the image coordinates of 5120 X 5120 TIFF image into my small cropped images using Python?

How can I incorporate the coordinate info of the original image into my cropped images, so I get the same coordinates when checking them in QGIS?

Comment: If you use rasterio in python, here is one way https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/290059/2856

Comment: Have you looked at the EarthPy library? There are clip and mask functions for rasters.