# Remove empty image - gdal_retile.py

Tags: python, gdal, tiles

I've been working with the `gdal_retile.py` script recently to retile an orthomosaic. I originally was using the solution from this [post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/285499/how-to-split-multiband-image-into-image-tiles-using-rasterio), but found that `gdal_retile.py` is faster with orthos > 10GB. There are a couple of features I added to that rasterio method that I want to add to the gdal_retile.py script, but I am just not sure where to add them.

Mainly, I do not want "empty" images. In my rasterio script I had `if np.all(data.read(window=window) == 0: continue`. These images were basically the images that were between the extent boundary and where the ortho actually contained the picture (data) - see attached image.

I've been trying to understand what the script is doing, but ultimately it's a bit beyond me. I believe I need to focus on the `createTile` function. I was able to find out if the `data` that is being written is empty, but I am unsure how to skip writing the raster when the conditions are met.

```
if bytearray(len(data)) == data:
    print('empty')
    continue
```

```
def createTile(minfo, offsetX, offsetY, width, height, tilename, OGRDS):
    """

    Create tile
    return name of created tile

    """

    if BandType is None:
        bt = minfo.band_type
    else:
        bt = BandType

    dec = AffineTransformDecorator([minfo.ulx, minfo.scaleX, 0, minfo.uly, 0, minfo.scaleY])

    s_fh = minfo.getDataSet(dec.ulx + offsetX * dec.scaleX, dec.uly + offsetY * dec.scaleY + height * dec.scaleY,
                            dec.ulx + offsetX * dec.scaleX + width * dec.scaleX,
                            dec.uly + offsetY * dec.scaleY)
                            
    if s_fh is None:
        return

    geotransform = [dec.ulx + offsetX * dec.scaleX, dec.scaleX, 0,
                    dec.uly + offsetY * dec.scaleY, 0, dec.scaleY]

    if OGRDS is not None:
        dec2 = AffineTransformDecorator(geotransform)
        points = dec2.pointsFor(width, height)
        addFeature(OGRDS, tilename, points[0], points[1])

    bands = minfo.bands

    if MemDriver is None:
        t_fh = Driver.Create(tilename, width, height, bands, bt, CreateOptions)
    else:
        t_fh = MemDriver.Create(tilename, width, height, bands, bt)

    if t_fh is None:
        print('Creation failed, terminating gdal_tile.')
        sys.exit(1)

    t_fh.SetGeoTransform(geotransform)
    if Source_SRS is not None:
        t_fh.SetProjection(Source_SRS.ExportToWkt())

    readX = min(s_fh.RasterXSize, width)
    readY = min(s_fh.RasterYSize, height)
    for band in range(1, bands + 1):
        s_band = s_fh.GetRasterBand(band)
        t_band = t_fh.GetRasterBand(band)
        
        if minfo.ct is not None:
            t_band.SetRasterColorTable(minfo.ct)
        if minfo.nodata is not None:
            t_band.Fill(minfo.nodata)
            t_band.SetNoDataValue(minfo.nodata)

        data = s_band.ReadRaster(0, 0, readX, readY, readX, readY, t_band.DataType)
        
        if bytearray(len(data)) == data:  #   <---- Added these three lines
            print('empty')                #   <-----
            continue                      #   <---------
            
        t_band.WriteRaster(0, 0, readX, readY, data, readX, readY, t_band.DataType)

    minfo.closeDataSet(s_fh)

    if MemDriver is not None:
        tt_fh = Driver.CreateCopy(tilename, t_fh, 0, CreateOptions)
        tt_fh.FlushCache()

    if Verbose:
        print(tilename + " : " + str(offsetX) + "|" + str(offsetY) + "-->" + str(width) + "-" + str(height))
```

Blue Tiles would be excluded when saving, but the grey tile would be saved because it contains data from the ortho.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that the `.tif` was actually being created on the lines `if MemDriver is None:` and not where `t_band.WriteRaster()` is located. So checking for an empty .tif should go right above that. See the new code below:

```
def createTile(minfo, offsetX, offsetY, width, height, tilename, OGRDS):
    """

    Create tile
    return name of created tile

    """

    if BandType is None:
        bt = minfo.band_type
    else:
        bt = BandType

    dec = AffineTransformDecorator([minfo.ulx, minfo.scaleX, 0, minfo.uly, 0, minfo.scaleY])

    s_fh = minfo.getDataSet(dec.ulx + offsetX * dec.scaleX, dec.uly + offsetY * dec.scaleY + height * dec.scaleY,
                            dec.ulx + offsetX * dec.scaleX + width * dec.scaleX,
                            dec.uly + offsetY * dec.scaleY)
                            
    if s_fh is None:
        return

    geotransform = [dec.ulx + offsetX * dec.scaleX, dec.scaleX, 0,
                    dec.uly + offsetY * dec.scaleY, 0, dec.scaleY]

    if OGRDS is not None:
        dec2 = AffineTransformDecorator(geotransform)
        points = dec2.pointsFor(width, height)
        addFeature(OGRDS, tilename, points[0], points[1])

    bands = minfo.bands


    #### ADDED HERE ####
    data = s_fh.GetRasterBand(1).ReadRaster()
    if bytearray(len(data)) == data:
        return
    #### ENDED HERE ####


    if MemDriver is None:
        t_fh = Driver.Create(tilename, width, height, bands, bt, CreateOptions)
    else:
        t_fh = MemDriver.Create(tilename, width, height, bands, bt)
```