# Creating automated clipping in QGIS

Tags: qgis, clip

I want to clip out 500 - 1000 cut-outs of 500px*500px of an image (a city area) (.tiff) and a shapefile layer above it (.json or .csv). These files are big for a manual process as I have to select the area manually and clip it. Is there any way this can be automated to cut the image into chunks of 500x500 pixels?

Comment: Perhaps this helps https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221671/how-to-split-a-tif-image-into-several-tiles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can propose how to clip part of the source image by 512*512 (or whatever size) tiles

1. Create AOI by which you clip source image
2. Perform Raster Extraction Clipper (Qgis 3.2)
   [image: Extracting by AOI]
3. Using plugin Qtiles (available in Qgis 2.18) perform extracting tiles 512*512 into some directory
   [image: Extracting tiles]
4. Then you have a lot of tile divided into several subdirectories respective to zoom level
   [image: Zoom 16]

Below parameters of one tile in Photoshop
[image: Tile parameters]

Comment: @JeevananthamSaravanan if the answer was helpful and solved your issue please select it as correct. This is done by ticking the green tick box next to the voting arrow on the answer.