# Splitting a georeferenced TIFF to multiple TIFFs using QGIS

Tags: qgis, tiles, vrt

I want to take a TIFF and split it to multiple TIFFs. I'm trying to do this with:

Right click on the layer -> Export -> Save As -> Checking "Create VRT".

The problem is that when loading the resulting tiles, they are in the same place, but lowered (like someone dragged down all the tiles for ~40 meters).

Any idea why could this happen?

Comment: A vrt is not tiles

Comment: @IanTurton, Oh. Is there an easy way to use QGIS to split the TIF to multiple TIFs?

Comment: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221671/splitting-tif-image-into-several-tiles works for me in QGIS 3.24 with no shift.

Comment: @IanTurton selecting "Create VRT" in the dialog and specifying tile size in the "VRT Tiles" - "Max columns" and "Max rows" will tile the output into multiple tiff files with a single mosaic VRT file.

Comment: @user2856, Is it possible this caused by me choosing 'wrong' tile size?

Comment: Don't know, try changing your tile sizes.

Comment: If the tiles are cut otherwise ok but there is that 40 m shift then I suppose that something special happens with coordinate system. Add gdalinfo report about the original image and about the splitted tile that is at the top-left corner.

Comment: Works for me too with no shift with QGIS 3.18. I would like to see the corner coordinates of a) your source image b) vrt_tiles.vrt. I suppose that you did not change the coordinate system by the same.