# Split raster in subrasters

Tags: python, gdal, sentinel-2

I have rasters of Sentinel-2 data and want to split them im subrasters (1km*1km). This is working so far but takes a lot of time due to the for loops in Python.

```
        ds = gdal.Open(d)
        
        llx, xres, xskew, uly, yskew, yres  = ds.GetGeoTransform()
        lly = uly + (ds.RasterYSize * yres)
        lrx = llx + (ds.RasterXSize * xres)

        lly_s = int(str(lly)[0:4]+'000')
        llx_s = int(str(llx)[0:3] + '000')
        
        for i, j in itertools.product(range(0, math.ceil(lrx-llx_s), 1000), range(0, math.ceil(uly-lly_s), 1000)):
            ulx_k = llx_s + i  #upper left x == lower left x
            lrx_k = ulx_k + 1000
        
            lry_k = lly_s + j 
            uly_k = lry_k + 1000
  
            translateOpt = gdal.TranslateOptions(format="Gtiff",projWin=(ulx_k, uly_k, lrx_k, lry_k),projWinSRS='epsg:25832', creationOptions = ["TILED=YES","COMPRESS=LZW"])
            ds = gdal.Translate(destName = f'{d[:-4]}_1000/{ulx_k}_{lry_k}.tif', srcDS=d, options = translateOpt)  
            ds.FlushCache()
            del ds
```

This is my code. It is working but really slow (kind of expected). Just wanted to know if someone knows a way to improve the performance.

Comment: Do any of these answers help? [Splitting .tif image into several tiles?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/221671/splitting-tif-image-into-several-tiles)

Comment: I looked at most of them but unfortunately they are either not ussable for my use case or require software that is not usable inside my script.